# Problema com Delphi 10.1 + FireDAC (AutoPost)

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10

Tenho uma *procedure* simples para salvar no banco de dados. Nela fiz também um controle casos os campos obrigatórios não sejam preenchido fazendo que o sistema evite gravar dados errados ou faltando informações.

Entretanto por mistério ou magia o registro é salvo no banco de dados. Não sei se tem alguma configuração do `_FireDAC_` nas tabela e ou no componente de conexão. Se alguém já passou por isso e puder me ajudar, agradeço.

## Código

```
procedure TfrmManutencaoUsuarios.btnSalvaUnidadeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // verifica os items
  if dbeUsuarioUnidade.Text = '' then
  begin
    Application.MessageBox('Campo Nome do Usuário é Obrigatório!','Aviso', 
        MB_OK+MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    dbeUsuarioUnidade.SetFocus;
    exit;
  end;

  if dbcUsuarioUnidade.Text = '' then
  begin
    Application.MessageBox('Nome da Unidade é Obrigatório!','Aviso', 
        MB_OK+MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    dbcUsuarioUnidade.SetFocus;
    exit;
  end;
  // Verifica se a Unidade já está acessível para o Usuário
  if DataModuleGeral.tbUsuariosUnidades.Locate('USUARIO_NOME;UNIDADE_NOME',
     VarArrayOf([dbeUsuarioUnidade.Text, dbcUsuarioUnidade.Text]),[]) then
  begin
    Application.MessageBox('Esta Unidade já está Acessível para este 
       usuário!','Aviso', MB_OK+MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    dbcUsuarioUnidade.SetFocus;
    exit;
  end else
  begin
    // Salva na Tabela
    DataModuleGeral.tbUsuariosUnidades.Post;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Vc usa FDQuery ou FDTable? Os campos na tabela do banco de dados tem um Default Value? E por último, qual banco vc está usando?

Comment: Usos FDTable, não tem um Default Value no Campo, o banco é Firebird

Comment: Um pouco difícil ajudar quando não conhecemos todo o código fonte. Mas há algumas possibilidades: 1. Algum outro ponto do fonte está dando post. Não necessariamente tem que haver a instrução Post, as vezes o fato de você navegar entre os registros da tabela, já gera um post. Isso pode estar acontecendo?  
Sugiro também ao invés de ver se o dbedit está preenchido, verificar direto na fdtable, exemplo: if tbUsuariosUnidades.Fieldbyname('nome').AsString = '' then...

Comment: Esse é todo o fonte do que grava no banco.
Não tem outro modo, você preenche o edite e aperta o botão o sistema verifica o se o edite esta vazio se sim ele sai se não ele fazer as outras verificações, mais o ponto em questão não é o edite e sim o final do código que mesmo encontrando  o registro no banco ele grava repetido...